# How to get correct values from MultipleChoiceField with ajax and vanilla JavaScript in Django

Tags: javascript, arrays, django, ajax, django-forms

### forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    AVAILABLE_OPTIONS = [
        ('a', 'a'),
        ('b', 'b'),
        ('c', 'c'),
    ]

    options = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        ......
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        choices=AVAILABLE_OPTIONS,
    )
```

### JavaScript

```
....
var my_array = []
var options = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=options]:checked');
....
```

### What I want:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ....., 'options': ['a', 'b', 'c', ....], ......}>
```

### What I get when printing request.POST

```
<QueryDict: {........,    'options': ['[object NodeList]'],     .....}>
```

And when I loop through `options`, and `my_array.push(options[i].value)`, I get the following, and the form doesn't work because it's 1 value, not multiple.

```
<QueryDict: {........,    'options': ['a, b, c'],     .....}>
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: Using a `FormData` object might make your code a bit simpler? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Retrieving_a_FormData_object_from_an_HTML_form

Comment: Sorry, it's still not working. All I continue getting is a `NodeList`. I know that is not an array, so I even tried with `new Array()`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code that is making the POST request?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I just figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

/facepalm

I forgot all I had to do was use the same `name` attribute in the post request to get the result I wanted.

```
xhr.send(`..... &options=${options[0].value}&options=${options[1].value}& ......`);
```